# Problem with Fabric for Unity Network Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a Problem with Fabric when I try to login I get an Network error.
I use the latest version and everything I try I get the error:

```
The authentication or decryption has failed
```

Error Login Screen:
[image: Login Screen with Network error]

Error Log:
[image: Error Log]

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: No I use the sdk from Fabric and when I try to login I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move To Mono Directory (In my case D:\Programiles\Unity2017\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.5> ) and Run mozroots --import --quiet
2. Answer all question to yes.
3. Login to Fablic